Why Touch Event of child Fragments is getting propagated to the parent ViewPager2

(Above is hierarchical structure, Inner view is inside middile view, which is inside Outer View)
So this my understanding of touchEvents given there is no dispatchTouchEvent.
If there is touch event on InnerView

Inner View can consume it
It Does not consume it will propagate to Middle View
Middle View Can consume it, if it Does not consume it will propagate to Outer View

Now I have a ViewPager2.

i have simple onTouchListener to check if touch is being propagated or not, like below
// Below code is in my main activity Code
findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.main_viewpager).setOnTouchListener{
            v,e->
            Log.d("TAG","ViewPager TouchEvent")
            false
        }

I also have same log statement added to my Fragment's root view's on touch listener
// Below code is in my Fragments onViewCreated method
//View is the root of the fragment
view.setOnTouchListener{
            v,e->
            Log.d("TAG","Fragment TouchEvent")
            false //Not consuming the touch
        }



Now if i touch inside my fragment.
Only Below statement is logged

"Fragment TouchEvent"
So even if the touch propagated to root of the Fragment, it did not propagated to viewPager

If i touch inside viewPager's padding area (blue area)

I can see "ViewPager TouchEvent" is logged
So my question is why the touch event is not propagated from ChildFragment to the Parent ViewPager2

Can you restructure your last paragraph so its more concise and have less "but"s? I have hard time grasping meaning of those sentences.

updated my question.

Even though you applied a listener that returns false on your innermost view the implementation of onTouchEvent() of ViewPager2's internal RecyclerView still stands. And it handles a lot of behaviors (most notably nested scrolling) that consume the touch preventing further propagation.
